# UITableViewCell subviews are not honoring the Autolayout constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, ipad

I'm drawing a fairly simple custom UITableViewCell--thumbnail on the left, name and link labels on the right. I want my name and link labels to be one-liners, truncating at the tail if texts exceed the cell's width. I am pretty sure that I am adding my constraints correctly, yet my name and link labels won't honor them.

This is what the cells look like on an iPhone 4S running iOS 8:

[image]

In my code, I am adding a 10-point trailing constraint for the name and link labels to the superview (the cell's `contentView`) and yet, notice that even at landscape, iOS doesn't seem to honor the constraints.

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong? This is my code for the whole cell. I am creating the views programatically and I have the Autolayout constraints in the table view cell's initializer.

```
#import "PopularWikiCell.h"

// Models
#import "Wiki.h"

// Pods
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"

// Constants
static const CGFloat kPadding = 10;
static const CGFloat kImageSize = 100;
const CGFloat kPopularWikiCellHeight = kImageSize + kPadding * 2;

@interface PopularWikiCell ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *thumbnailView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *nameLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UILabel *linkLabel;

@end

@implementation PopularWikiCell

- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    if (self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {
        // Initialise the subviews.
        _thumbnailView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        _thumbnailView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
        _thumbnailView.clipsToBounds = YES;

        _nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _nameLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
        _nameLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        _nameLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;
        _nameLabel.text = @"Name";

        _linkLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        _linkLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        _linkLabel.text = @"Link";
        _linkLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
        _linkLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail;

        // Add the subviews.
        [self.contentView addSubview:_thumbnailView];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_nameLabel];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_linkLabel];

        _thumbnailView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        _nameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        _linkLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
        self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        // Add the layout constraints.

        NSDictionary *metrics = @{@"kPadding" : @(kPadding),
                                  @"kImageSize" : @(kImageSize)};
        NSDictionary *views = @{@"thumbnailView" : _thumbnailView,
                                @"nameLabel" : _nameLabel,
                                @"linkLabel" : _linkLabel};

        NSArray *constraints = @[@"H:|-kPadding-[thumbnailView(kImageSize)]-kPadding-[nameLabel]-kPadding-|",
                                 @"H:[thumbnailView]-kPadding-[linkLabel]-kPadding-|",
                                 @"V:|-kPadding-[nameLabel]-0-[linkLabel]",
                                 @"V:|-kPadding-[thumbnailView(kImageSize)]"];

        [self.contentView addConstraintsFromVisualFormatStrings:constraints
                                                        options:0
                                                        metrics:metrics
                                                          views:views];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setWiki:(Wiki *)wiki
{
    _wiki = wiki;

    self.thumbnailView.image = nil;
    self.thumbnailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    [self.thumbnailView setImageWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:wiki.thumbnailURL]
                              placeholderImage:nil
                                       success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                                           __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
                                           strongSelf.thumbnailView.image = image;
                                           strongSelf.thumbnailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
                                       }
                                       failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                                       }];

    self.nameLabel.text = wiki.name;
    self.linkLabel.text = wiki.URL;

    [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Selection removes all background colors so re-set it.
    [self resetSubviewBackgroundColors];

    [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)setHighlighted:(BOOL)highlighted animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setHighlighted:highlighted animated:animated];

    // Highlighing removes all background colors so re-set it.
    [self resetSubviewBackgroundColors];

    [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)resetSubviewBackgroundColors
{
    if (self.thumbnailView.image) {
        self.thumbnailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    } else {
        self.thumbnailView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Are you adding the constraint in IB?

Comment: @YuviGr Hi, no I am not. All of my views and subviews are being created programatically in this app.

Comment: then you have to calculate the length of the string, ill post a answer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is hidden in

```
self.contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

removing this code fixes your issue.

if you don't want *traslate Autoresizing Mask Into Constraints* - set yours desirable constraints for cell.contentView.

Answer (score 1):

In your cellForRow: method make sure you are calling:

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"" forIndexPath:(IndexPath *)
```

calling this returns a cell of the correct size (important for autolayout)

if this doesn't fix it, inside your cell implement:

```
-(void)layoutSubview{ 
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [self layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First i highly recommend using autolayout, it solves a lot of size problems and many calculations

But, if you are not setting a constraints then you have to calculate the length of the string to fit the width of the label you want

```
NSString *string = @"this is a very long string to fit into a UILabel";
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 50, 150, 20)];
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:15.0];
label.font = font;
label.text = string;
CGSize stringSize = [string sizeWithAttributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : font}];

// check if the string is wider then the label
if (stringSize.width > label.bounds.size.width) {
    NSString *newString = [string substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, string.length/2)]; <----  i just divided the string into two -----
    // check if the newString fits the label
    // if not the divide again

    label.text = newString;
}else{
    label.text = string;
}
[self.view addSubview:label];
```

like i wrote in the code, i just divided the string into two strings. This might not work if you have a very long string, so you need to keep checking in the string fits the label.

You can use the:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@...", [string substringToIndex:20]];
```

to add "..." at the end of the string

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this in your custom UITableViewCell, set the frame of the content view or Labels or any elements using these :-

In Declaration :-

```
GRect usableSpace;
CGFloat usableWidth, usableHeight;
```

In Implementation :-

```
usableSpace = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
usableWidth = usableSpace.size.width;
usableHeight = usableSpace.size.height;
```

and then set the frame using these widths and height

Answer (score 0):

I can't load your image so I'm not sure what problem you've got.

I see this code, is there a typo?

```
NSArray *constraints = 
@[
@"H:|-kPadding-[thumbnailView(kImageSize)]-kPadding-[nameLabel]-kPadding-|",
@"H:[thumbnailView]-kPadding-[linkLabel]-kPadding-|",  //this line you forgot the left edge
@"V:|-kPadding-[nameLabel]-0-[linkLabel]",
@"V:|-kPadding-[thumbnailView(kImageSize)]"
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting an incorrect width even though my views looked good, the underlying CGRect was wrong.

It became apparent when using a `CAShapeLayer` to add a border to my cells.

I fixed it by calling `layoutIfNeeded()` on the `contentView`

```
 override func layoutSubviews() {
     super.layoutSubviews()
     contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```